# Modal boostrap dentro UpdatePanel após evento click fundo escuro

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

Tenho um modal `boostrap` poup dentro de um componente `ASPX UpdatePanel` dentro desse modal tenho um botão `ASP btnEditar` com evento click para executar uma rotina de `update`. Após executar o evento o modal fecha mas seu fundo escurecido fica na pagina impossibilitando qualquer ação!

Chamada do modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar">
<i data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="fa fa-edit">
</i></button>
```

Modal:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="modalEditar" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfListID" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCodAgenciaAlterar" runat="server" />

                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <strong><i class="fa fa-map-marker margin-r-5">
                                                </i>Cidade da Agência</strong>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCidadeEditar"
                                                autocomplete="off" CssClass="form-control" 
                                                placeholder="Ex: Itapira"
                                                runat="server" onkeypress="return somenteLetras(event);">
                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <strong><i class="fa fa-university margin-r-5">
                                                </i>Código Agência</strong>

                                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodAgenciaEditar" MaxLength="4"
                                                autocomplete="off" CssClass="form-control" 
                                                placeholder="Ex: 9999   => 4 dígitos"
                                                runat="server" onkeypress="return PermiteSomenteNumeros(event);" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="info" style="text-align: center">
                                        <strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle text-light-blue margin-r-5"></i>
                                            <span class="text-light-blue">Essa ação editará</span></strong>
                                        <br />
                                        <strong><span class="text-light-blue margin-r-5">9 processos!</span></strong>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEditar" OnClick="btnEditar_Click"
                                CssClass="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="Editar"></asp:Button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Fim -->

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o evento do botão editar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me orientar em uma possível solução para esse evento.

Comment: Não vejo nenhum updatePanel e nem o javascript do seu botão

Comment: Tente inspecionar o modal e veja como estão as classes. Eu acho que você deveria botar o modal fora do update panel.

Comment: @Phiter Fora do Update Panel ele fecha normalmente! Mas se o usuário atualizar a pagina, o evento click é executado novamente. Dentro do UpdatePanel eu evito o postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você abre o modal, o bootstrap cria uma div com o seguinte markup, antes do fechamento da tag `<body>`:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

Essa é a div que faz o fundo da página ficar escuro.

Como você colocou o modal dentro do `UpdatePanel`, quando esse painel é atualizado, o html é atualizado e outro modal é criado. Porém o modal anterior, que estava ligado ao backdrop criado, não existe mais. Não há evento javascript fechando o modal da forma correta (`$().modal('hide')`).

Acredito que a melhor solução é tirar o modal do `UpdatePanel`, ou simplesmente rodar esse código após a atualização do `UpdatePanel`:

```
$("body").removeClass('modal-open').find('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: Após a atualização do UpdatePanel fiz a chamada da função `$("body").removeClass('modal-open').find('.modal-backdrop').remove();` e funcionou perfeitamente!